# grunt-locales, building html

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, gruntjs

I'm using the grunt-locales project to turn i18n json objects into javascript functions that can be used by my Angularjs app.  It works great when with static and dynamic content, but I'm having issues when I try to use html.

That is if I have the following json

```
  "_Hello": {
      "value": "Hello in English",
      "files": [
       "app/views/loginScreen.html"
      ]
  },
```

and use gurnt locales:build, a javascript function is produced that returns the string "Hello in English" which is exactly what I'm looking for

But If I try to add html in my translation like

```
  "_Hello": {
      "value": "<h2 ng-directive>Hello in English</h2>",
      "files": [
       "app/views/loginScreen.html"
      ]
  },
```

Where the goal is to add a directive within the translations.  If I run grunt locales:build on this, I get a javascript function that returns

```
  <h2>Hello in English</h2>
```

Gurnt-locales removes my ng-directive attribute!

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RobertLevy I haven't. I found work arounds for all of the scenarios I was trying to this.  I now that setting locales.build.htmlmin to false helped for some of the classes and hrefs.